# Branch on ?: operator?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, hardware, micro-optimization

For a typical modern compiler on modern hardware, will the `? :` operator result in a branch that affects the instruction pipeline?

In other words which is faster, calling both cases to avoid a possible branch:

```
bool testVar = someValue(); // Used later.
purge(white);
purge(black);
```

or picking the one actually needed to be purged and only doing it with an operator `?:`:

```
bool testVar = someValue();
purge(testVar ? white : black);
```

I realize you have no idea how long purge() will take, but I'm just asking a general question here about whether I would ever want to call purge() twice to avoid a possible branch in the code.

I realize this is a very tiny optimization and may make no real difference, but would still like to know.  I expect the `?:` does not result in branching, but want to make sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the function call will be far more expensive than branching, but I don't know enough to back that up and post it as an answer. Why don't you try both and profile?

Comment: FYI, `?:` is known as the *ternary* operator.

Comment: Why don't you try it with your compiler and see? Just look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @Jared Ng - Not quite. A ternary operator is any operator with three operands. Most languages only have one ternary operator - `?:` - but some (somewhere) have others. Ternary is similar to binary or unary. `?:` is _a_ ternary operator, but it's name is the _conditional_ operator.

Comment: Don't the two have different behaviors? Just code for the behavior you need.

Comment: @Chris Hmm... good catch. I was being too specific.

Comment: @GMan - I'd assume (since the OP seems to be implying that either option is acceptable) that `purge`ing something that presumably wasn't needed is a nop (perhaps not in the assembly, but in the effect).

Comment: I'm seconding @ChrisLutz -- just profile it and see it for your specific application. There are many tricks the compiler and CPU bring to the table, so human beings can't profile in their head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CMOV (Conditional MOVe) instruction has been part of the x86 instruction set since the Pentium Pro. It is rarely automatically generated by GCC because of compiler options commonly used and restrictions placed by the C language. A SETCC/CMOV sequence can be inserted by inline assembly in your C program. This should only be done is cases where the conditional variable is a randomly oscillating value in the inner loop (millions of executions) of a program. In non-oscillating cases and in cases of simple patterns of oscillation, modern processors can predict branches with a very high degree of accuracy. In 2007, [Linus Torvalds suggested here](http://ondioline.org/mail/cmov-a-bad-idea-on-out-of-order-cpus) to avoid use of CMOV in most situations.

Intel describes the conditional move in the [Intel(R) Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference Manual](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf):

> The CMOVcc instructions check the state of one or more of the status
> flags in the EFLAGS register (CF, OF, PF, SF, and ZF) and perform a
> move operation if the flags are in a specified state (or condition). A
> condition code (cc) is associated with each instruction to indicate
> the condition being tested for. If the condition is not satisfied, a
> move is not performed and execution continues with the instruction
> following the CMOVcc instruction.
>
> These instructions can move a 16- or 32-bit value from memory to a
> general-purpose register or from one general-purpose register to
> another. Conditional moves of 8-bit register operands are not
> supported.
>
> The conditions for each CMOVcc mnemonic is given in the description
> column of the above table. The terms “less” and “greater” are used for
> comparisons of signed integers and the terms “above” and “below” are
> used for unsigned integers.
>
> Because a particular state of the status flags can sometimes be
> interpreted in two ways, two mnemonics are defined for some opcodes.
> For example, the CMOVA (conditional move if above) instruction and the
> CMOVNBE (conditional move if not below or equal) instruction are
> alternate mnemonics for the opcode 0F 47H.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the platform.  Specifically, it depends on the size of jump prediction table of the CPU and whether the CPU allows conditional operations (like on ARM).

CPUs with conditional operations will strongly favor the second case.  CPUs with bigger jump prediction tables will favor the first case.

The real answer (like with any other performance questions): measure and compare.  Sometimes the rest of the code throws a curve ball and it's usually impossible to predict effects of some changes.

Comment: Most modern ISAs have some form of conditional-select, like x86-64 `cmov`,  AArch64 `csel`, MIPS `movz`.  For cases where the two options to select from don't require any extra computation, most compilers will compile a simple ternary to that.  (On some ISAs, like 32-bit ARM and I think Itanium, it's actually possible to avoid stalling on cache-miss loads whose value won't be needed without branching, which makes it even better to do branchlessly.  On ARM via actual conditional loads, or on Itanium via speculative loads, I think.)

Comment: Even without an instruction like `cmov`, a bithack can turn a boolean into a 0 / 0xffffffff mask that can be used with and/or to implement the same operation.  On a few CPUs a compiler might even choose to do that, especially for operations like 2's complement `abs()` where a branchless bithack just for that is only a couple instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine the first method would ever be faster.

With the first method you may avoid a branch, but you replace it with a function call, which would usually involve a branch plus a lot more (unless it was inlined).  Even if inlined, unless the functionality inside the purge() function was absolutely trivial it would almost certainly be slower.

Comment: Not necessarily.  That unconditional branch won't require the pipeline to be flushed.  If the function is relatively simple, it *may* be cheaper overall.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function is at least as expensive as doing a logic test + jump (and yes, the `? :` ternary operator would require a jump).

Comment: Assuming this is all happening frequently inside a loop, the unconditional function call will not incur a branch misprediction, and so will not require the CPU pipeline to be flushed.  The logic test may involve a conditional jump; this will be much more expensive than the unconditional jump.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case purge is called twice. In the second case purge is called once

Its hard to answer the question about branching because its so dependent on compilers and instruction set. For example on an ARM (which has conditional instruction execution) it might not branch. ON an x86 it almost certainly will