# Bitwise manipulation setting variable on a condition

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have three variables- x,y and z in a C/C++ application. I would like to set x = y, when z == 3. I can do this using multiplication:

```
x = y * (z == 3)
```

but this is being called in a large loop and the IMUL will take 4 CPU cycles. I was hoping to find a bit manipulation which would take 1 CPU cycle.

EDIT: Compiler MSVC 64-bit compilation, Platform Win 7 64, x86 architecture, Ivy Bridge or Haswell.

Comment: You say "will take" rather than "does take". Have you looked at the produced assembly to confirm?

Comment: `z == 3` will resolves to a boolean so it will be either 0 or 1, so the result will either be y or 0.

Comment: Depending on the platform, conditionals may be better. For example, most ARM instructions are conditional, and the compiler can take advantage of that.

Comment: Also, like @ddriver mentioned, if `z` is not 3, then `x` will be set to 0. Is this what you intended?

Comment: What does this question have to do with bit manipulation at all?

Comment: The result at present is either `y` or `2*y`!!!

Comment: "C/C++" isn't a thing. And you should mention your compiler and platform.

Comment: Integer ALU operations on the architecture your specified should take 1 single cycle. http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html - page 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On two's complement, the expression:

```
(y * (z == 3))
```

is the same as:

```
(y & -(z == 3))
```

However, it is doubtful that either will perform significantly differently from the other. Consider the following code compiled with `gcc -O3 -S`:

```
int foo1 (int y, int z) { return y * (z == 3); }
int foo2 (int y, int z) { return y & -(z == 3); }
int foo3 (int y, int z) { if (z == 3) return y; else return 0; }
```

For `foo1()`:

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    $3, 8(%esp)
    sete    %al
    imull   4(%esp), %eax
```

For `foo2()`, there is one more instruction (although maybe it is cheaper):

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    $3, 8(%esp)
    sete    %al
    negl    %eax
    andl    4(%esp), %eax
```

But, for `foo3()`, you get:

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    $3, 8(%esp)
    cmove   4(%esp), %eax
```

Although it is a conditional move instruction, the code doesn't get much tighter than that.

Comment: Yes, but it sets `x` to either `y` or `2y`, which is in contrast with the question itself (of course, that is OP's issue, not yours).

Answer (score 3):

Write:

```
if ( z == 3 )
    x = y * 2;
else
    x = y;
```

(or whatever else you edit your question to next) and activate your compiler. That's what compilers are for. You say what you want with compiler switches and the compiler does it better than you could.

Answer (score 1):

This must be at least two operations (possibly 3).

1. Evaluating `z == 3`
2. Assignment to `x`.
3. (possible) Evaluating `y + y`

The most efficient way I can think of to write it would be with a ternary expression.

```
x = (z == 3) ? y + y : y;
```

Comment: I have seen ternary expressions used before in things like this- I don't understand why they don't incur branching? (I thought they were just syntactic sugar for IF-ELSE statements).

Comment: The ternary expression doesn't actually give the same result - when `z==3` is false, OP's expression sets `x` to zero, but yours doesn't change `x`

Comment: It depends, but it is likely that your ternary will not cause branching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127759/branch-on-operator

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You are correct, I edited the ternary expression.

Comment: Oh I just edited my Q as you made me realise something, but dont worry thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user997112 Please see my most recent edit, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
x = (z == 3) ? y : x;
```

Complicated way

```
x = y & (-(z == 3)); // Based on -1 = 1111...11 binary
```